# I am trying to make a new directory and i keep getting an error

Tags: powershell, directory

In Powershell when trying to make a new directory like so...

`md c:\test`

It gives me a  syntax error message and points to my c drive. I thought it might be because it was lower case but tried it again in capital and got the same results... I also tried doing it the New-item way but got the same thing?Also as you can probably tell I am a noob so keep it kinda simple please and thanks.

Comment: Can you give the syntax error you get using this command line ? It should work.

Comment: Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax @JPBlanc

Comment: Are you sure you are using PowerShell ? can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: I don't know how if I can but I am positive it is Powershell v2.7.8 with the blue background.

Comment: Can you transcript the value of `$PSVersionTable` ?

Comment: No, I got another Invalid syntax error.

Comment: Your are not on Microsoft PowerShell or if so you should reinstall it. What is your operatin system ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 @JPBlanc also does it matter that I am the administrator

Comment: Okay well now I feel slow. I figured it out, it wouldn't work because I had python on. Lol, facepalm. @JPBlanc

Answer (score 0):

Well double check and make sure you quit python.